# Why react shows TypeError: undefined has no properties even after passing it properties?

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching users and passing it to `Users` component.
However, the browser shows TypeError: undefined has no properties.

```
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './components/navbar/NavBar';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Component } from 'react';
import Users from './components/users/Users';
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        users: [],
        loading: false,
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            loading: true,
        });
        const response = await axios.get('http://api.github.com/users');
        const userData = response.data;
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            users: userData,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='App'>
                <NavBar title={'Github Finder'} icon={'fab fa-github'} />
                <div className='container'>
                    <Users loading={this.state.loading} users={this.state.users} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I am passing the loading and users as a prop to the Users Component.
Here is Users component.

```
import UserItem from './UserItem';
import React from 'react';

const Users = (props) => {
    const userStyle = {
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3,1fr)',
        gridGap: '1rem',
    };

    if (this.props.loading) {
        return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    } else {
        return (
            <div style={userStyle}>
                {this.props.users.map((user) => (
                    <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
};
export default Users;
```

Error is shown pointing here: I do not understand why its showing this error. When the props has been passed.

```
  10 | 
> 11 | if (this.props.loading) {
     | ^  12 |  return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  13 | } else {
  14 |  return (
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **`Users` is a [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), there is no `this`**

So just remove `this`:

```
if (props.loading) {  // <-- REMOVE "THIS"
        return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
```

**And also here:**

```
<div style={userStyle}>
                {props.users.map((user) => (  // <-- REMOVE "THIS"
                    <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
                ))}
            </div>
```

Comment: It says TypeError: props.users is undefined. But I am passing it via prop name `users` in App.js

Answer (score 1):

You are using react ES6 arrow function functional Component. If you use this, the object points to the Window Object that is Document Object Model Window Object.

You should use

`const Users = ({loading}) => {}`  and then consume `loading` or

`const Users = (props) => {}` and then consume `props.loading`